# Unable to store session data into next form

Tags: php, html, validation, session, post

Currently I am on a question to store session and pass it to the next form, but as hard as I try to start session and store the variable inside the session, it does not work. Please shed some light on this, thanks!

**MainForm.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require("inputValidation.php"); // This php file is just a file that does validation for my side
$validForm = true;
if ($_POST) 
{
}
?>
<form class="form" action="nextform.php" role="form" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value= "<?php
                        if (isset($_POST['name'])) 
                            {
                            if (!validateRequired($_POST['name'])) 
                            {
                                $_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['name'];
                                $validForm = false;          
                            }
                            if (validateRequired($_POST['name'])) 
                            {
                                $_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['name'];
                                $validForm = true;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

**nextform.php**

```
print_r ($_SESSION);
```

The problem is even if i enter any value inside the textbox name, I will be just redirected straight to nextform.php without getting my session value. Why is this so? Is there any way I can get my session value without changing `action="nextform.php"`?

Thank you!

Sorry I am still new to sessions and PHP so bear with me :)

Comment: Where do you set $_POST['name'], is it set? session_start(); needs to be the first thing in nextform.php, too -- Session needs to be started in every page you want to use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you wan't to do is move the whole

```
if (isset($_POST['name']))
{
    //... you code
}
```

to the page where the form is submitted, in your case `nextform.php`.

Your pages should be something like:

**MainForm.php**

```
<form class="form" action="nextform.php" role="form" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value= "">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

**nextform.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require("inputValidation.php"); // This php file is just a file that does validation for my side
$validForm = true;

if (isset($_POST['name'])) 
{
    if (!validateRequired($_POST['name'])) 
    {
        $_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['name'];
        $validForm = false;          
    }
    if (validateRequired($_POST['name'])) 
    {
        $_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['name'];
        $validForm = true;
    }
}

if($validForm) {
    echo "Validation success";
    print_r ($_SESSION);
} else {
    echo "Form validation failed.";
}
?>
```

Basically you can access the `POST` parameters in the page where the form is submitted, see `action="nextform.php"`.

Here you can check if the form was submitted and do the proper validation, along with redirecting the user somewhere, or just showing the appropriate messages as needed, ie `Validation failed` or `Validation success`.

Comment: One comment, the way you use `validateRequired()` is a bit odd, since whether it fails or not you still set the session to the posted value but i guess it doesn't really matter here since you are playing with the code.

Comment: Hi @Krypos, thank you for your time. I will try it out later and keep you updated.